# Sorting data frame of transactions in R

Tags: r, sorting

My data is in a file named CspadeData.txt, it is rather large (11 million rows). I linked it from my [google drive here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6VvhxxLVGccRVo4NEdyMEN4dFE/view?usp=sharing).

I am trying to use this data in the `cspade()` function:

```
library(arulesSequences)

x <- read_baskets(con = "CspadeData.txt", info = c('sequenceID','eventID','SIZE'), sep = ' ')

s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1), 
             control = list(memsize = 65536, verbose = TRUE))
parameter specification:
support : 0
maxsize : 1
maxlen  : 1

algorithmic control:
bfstype  : FALSE
verbose  :  TRUE
summary  : FALSE
tidLists : FALSE
memsize  : 65536

preprocessing ...Error in makebin(data, file) : 'eid' invalid (strict order)
```

I know this error is telling me that my eventID column is not in order. So I executed the following code to order my data by sequenceID and eventID.

```
data <- read.table(file = "CspadeData.txt", sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(data)
data <- data[order(data$V1,data$V2),]
write.table(data, file = "CspadeData.txt", sep = " ", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

But when I rerun the `cspade()` function I still get the error 'eid' invalid even though I ordered my data by `sequenceID` and `eventID`. Is there something else wrong with my data that is throwing this error?

Comment: Maybe some of the event ids is "syntactically" invalid, like just a space or something. At least that's how you can provoke the error. read_baskets already warns you in case of order problems. Btw: Did you find a solution to your [prev question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492087/cspade-r-error)?

Comment: @lukeA Im not 100% positive, but I think the other post had something to do with the maxwin option.

Comment: If my eventID column is listed as an int when I call str(data) doesn't that mean there cant be extra spaces? Otherwise it would format the column as a chr variable type?

Comment: I'd think so - does cspade also throw the error with numeric eventIDs? My pc cannot process such amounts of data, thus I cannot reproduce this other then by trial and error.

Comment: I use the read_baskets() function to read in the data from a txt file. Since cspade() doesn't use data frames. Im not sure I can change the variable type.